# I need to pass a parameter from request header to the API controller action method. How can I?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I am using WEB API 2.0 for REST Service development and I need to pass a parameter from request header to the API controller action method. How can I?

By default API controller is reading the parameters from request body. 
How can I make it read parameter from request header?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("abc")]
public IHttpActionResult abcMethod(string s)
{
   //some code
}
```

I want the above abcMethod to read it's parameter from request header.

Pls suggest.

Comment: IMHO, request headers are not meant for the application to use. The Querystring parameters are alone to be interpreted by the application as parameters. If you can provide the usecase, it will be helpful to discuss further.

Comment: Oh.. In that case, What is best way to read some sensitive data using HttpPost method?

Comment: Using SSL over HTTP or using encrypted data, we can send the sensitive data. Since HTTPS encrypts the entire payload, anything inside the request cannot be eavesdropped

Comment: Let me actually tell you the scenario. I am writing REST services for a mobile application to consume. And the UI team is sending GUID along with other parameters to my post service request. We want the GUID to be separated from other parameters of the request body. Is there any way other than request body and uri? Please be kind. I am  a new bee. Let me know if my qn isn't clear.

Comment: AFAIK, even the access token from aAuth server  is sent in request body and no other special means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...

```
IEnumerable<string> headerValues = request.Headers.GetValues("MyCustomID");
var id = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: IEnumerable<string> does not contain a definition for FirstOrDefault and no extension method found. Do I need to reference any assemlbly??

Comment: add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Yeah. It is working. Thanks a lot!! But saravanan in his comment above, suggested that headers are not meant to be used by the application. Anyway I will convey this to my co developers and decide!! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to the Web API 2, but I usually do

```
string variale = this.Request.Headers.GetValues("HeaderParameter").First();
```

Any of the FirstOrDefault, Single, SingleOrDefault() or anything of the like will work.

Also, Lambda works as well:

```
string variable = this.Request.Headers.First(header => header.Key == "Parameter").Value.FirstOrDefault();
```